# Multiple jQuery niceScroll plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I have jQuery niceScroll setup, its working fine on the body, however I want to have different themed scrollbars on the same page. I have the following code:

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JPA4R/135/

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#267ec8", cursorwidth:"10px"});
    $("#test").niceScroll({cursorcolor:"#ffffff", cursorwidth:"5px"});
  });
 </script>
```

Link: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

Body i want to have a blue scrollbar and on div i have i want the scrollbar to be white and thinner. However with the code above the one on the body is working but not the one on the div?

Is it possible to have multiple on the same page? Any help would be great, i am stuck and cannot see anything wrong with the above.

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, when I read the docs right, then is applying it on the body-elements means using it at a main style for all scrollbars. Did you trie it with 2 different divs instead of using a div and the body?

Comment: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html Demo has different colors on parent and child - so, I'd say it's possible... maybe look at that source.

Comment: Is possibile, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6m97gwb/3/) there is a working example. You'll see that is working on `body` and `#test` elements. Do a fiddle with your code where you are working on.

Comment: Hi, heres the link to all the code, this example nothing works > http://jsfiddle.net/p6m97gwb/4/ Hope u guys can help, thanks

Comment: Heres one with the body scrollbar, just cant get the one in the blue div working: http://jsfiddle.net/JPA4R/135/

Comment: I think the problem is with your CSS, beacuse your element are not floating as it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/):

> 4. DIV with "wrapper", formed by two divs, the first is the vieport, the latter is the content:

```
$(document).ready(

  function() { 

      $("#viewportdiv").niceScroll("#wrapperdiv",{cursorcolor:"#00F"});

  }

);
```

In your fiddle exemple you are calling `niceScroll` this way:

```
$(".filterContainer").niceScroll({
    cursorcolor: "#ffffff",
    cursorwidth: "5px"
});
```

In your html code `.filterContainer`(content) is **wrapped** by `#sidebar-wrapper`(viewport) element.

So you have to modify the way how `niceScroll` is call. So, following what the documentation says:

```
$("#sidebar-wrapper").niceScroll(".filterContainer",{
    cursorcolor: "#ffffff",
    cursorwidth: "5px"
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6m97gwb/5/) a working example.